# How to get URL endpoint detail as variable in Serverless Framework's `serverless.yml` file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

Using [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/framework/) to
deploy AWS Lambda functions, Serverless creates (or receives) the
specific URL endpoint string. I want to use that string (as a variable)
in another section of the `serverless.yml` specification file.

Is that URL endpoint available as a variable in `serverless.yml`?
The [Serverless Framework documentation on AWS-related variables](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/)
does not seem to answer that case.

---

Details: my `serverless.yml` contains a `provider:` specification
similar to:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  memorySize: 512
  region: ${opt:region, 'eu-west-1'}
  profile: ${opt:profile, 'default'}
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'staging'}
```

and a `functions:` section starting with:

```
functions:
  round-control:
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-round-control
    runtime: nodejs8.10
    handler: round/control/app.lambdaHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: round/control
          method: get
```

After a

`serverless deploy --profile [my-aws-profile]`

the Lambda function `sample-experiments-staging-round-control`
is reported to be available at endpoint
`https://1a234bc5de.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/staging/round/control`.

Question: is there a variable in Serverless available that contains
that `1a234bc5de`, or `1a234bc5de.execute-api` or perhaps even 
`1a234bc5de.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`?
(Obviously, I can also construct the last two if I know the first.)

With that variable, I can construct the full URL endpoint, which I
need in another place in the `serverless.yml` file.

N.B. That `1a234bc5de` isn't a dynamically generated random
string - my current project is (per stage, per region) 'fixed' to
the same string. Perhaps that string is generated at AWS Lambda or
AWS API Gateway?

Comment: This might help: http://www.goingserverless.com/blog/api-gateway-url

Comment: Great, @jarmod. It appears to be available in a CloudFormation variable. It's documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html and the `Ref` on the `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` resource contains that Id.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to pass the URL and unique ID for the API Gateway endpoint to a Lambda function as environment variables as follows:

```
  mylambda:
    handler: mylambda.handler
    runtime: python3.7
    events:
    - http:
        path: id
        cors: true
    environment:
      APIG_UID: !Ref "ApiGatewayRestApi"
      APIG_URL:
        !Join
          - ''
          - - 'https://'
            - !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
            - '.execute-api.'
            - ${opt:region, self:provider.region}
            - '.amazonaws.com/'
            - ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
```

Thanks to [goingserverless](http://www.goingserverless.com/blog/api-gateway-url).

Comment: Yep, that works. Just curious: can that `Ref` on `ApiGatewayRestApi` only be passed to a function _via an environment variable_?

Comment: I think environment variables is the simplest way to get configuration data into a Lambda function. Another good way would be to save it in Parameter Store (you could do this in the same serverless template afaik) and provide the parameter store key to the Lambda function. Another option, for large amounts of config data, would be to write it to a JSON file and bundle that with your Lambda package, but that would require additional build time scripting (and perhaps retrieving the API Gateway info from CloudFormation stack outputs).

Comment: OK. Initially I was hoping that that variable would be passable to another Lambda function via the HTTP request path or as a variable in the query string. That would have been most logical (perhaps just in my case), but passing it via the environment is fine as well.

Comment: No, I'll try to avoid build time scripting. I already have a Go function body that I need to compile towards the correct OS target for AWS Lambdas before that function gets deployed via Serverless. I'm trying to move away from that requirement.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a simpler and more modern alternative:

```yaml
provider:
  environment:
    API_URL: !Sub 'https://${ApiGatewayRestApi}.execute-api.${aws:region}.amazonaws.com/${sls:stage}'
```

Note: the code above applies to **[REST API](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway)** (API Gateway v1), not **HTTP API**.

If you are using the new [HTTP API](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api) (API Gateway v2), the solution is simpler:

```yaml
provider:
  environment:
    API_URL: !GetAtt HttpApi.ApiEndpoint
```