# How to output resource path from serverless framework on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

How do I output the resource path/URL to cloudformation Outputs?

For example, I have a lambda that's listening for a http event on path `/hello` and I'd like the cloudformation to output a variable with the value `https://kjkjwerwer.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/hello`

By default serverless framework outputs the `ServiceEndpoint`, however, I wanted the full endpoint of each of my functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output anything you'd like in the `resources` section.
You can use all the same templating variables like `!Ref`, `${self:custom.myEndpointName}`, and `!Join` to clean it up:

```yaml
resources:
  Outputs:
    MyEndpointName:
      Description: HTTP Endpoint for MyEndpoint lambda
      Value: ${self:custom.myEndpointName} // Or some other templated/hardcoded string
```

Comment: Apologies, I had to updated the question, I wanted to output the full endpoint, eg: `https://kjkjwerwer.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/hello` not just the `/hello` - any idea how to do that please?

Comment: It's the same answer, you'll want to use Fn::Join to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542422/how-to-get-url-endpoint-detail-as-variable-in-serverless-frameworks-serverless

Comment: You're a genius, thank you so you much for your help today, and a couple of days ago too :)

Comment: Sure thing, anytime!